# Disable multiple logins in one step

Tags: sql-server, security, users, logins, ddl

Is there a way to disable multiple sql logins based on a set of users in a table? For example:

```
ALTER LOGIN (Select userid from tbl_user) DISABLE;
```

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't feed a query to an `ALTER LOGIN` command. But you can build the command pretty easily using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',
        @cmd nvarchar(550) = N'ALTER LOGIN $$$ DISABLE;' 
                           + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SELECT @sql += REPLACE(@cmd, N'$$$', QUOTENAME(userid))
  FROM dbo.tbl_user;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

When you're happy with the output, uncomment the `EXEC`.

Note that if you have ***a lot*** of users in that table, you won't be able to see the whole command using `PRINT`, since there are limitations in output length. See **[this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)** for workarounds.

Also, there is no error handling here, so you should probably actually either add `TRY`/`CATCH` or join to `sys.server_principals` to make sure you are disabling logins that actually exist:

```
SELECT @sql += REPLACE(@cmd, N'$$$', QUOTENAME(p.name))
  FROM dbo.tbl_user AS u
  INNER JOIN master.sys.server_principals AS p
  ON p.name = u.userid;
```